# Router adds 40ms of latency + decreases download speed by 20mbps

Tags: networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have router tplink TL-WR940N and noticed that recently it started to kind of throttle my internet, I ran few tests in online games & on speedtest and I noticed that on speedtest results with direct connection from my kind of internet modem / antenna to pc with ethernet cable are around 10 +/- 2ms latency and 55mbps +/- 5mbps download, when I connect my pc to internet via router, so that "connection graph" looks like

`[antenna] -> ethernet -> [router] -> ethernet -> [pc]`

then speedtests are getting way worse, my results with router are 40 +/- 10ms latency and 25 +/- 5mbps download speed, what could be the issue?

I also spotted it in online games - when I play via router then I have pings like 60-80, sometimes even bigger than 100 in extreme cases, while when I tried playing with direct connection I got literally pings in area of 10-30, in extreme  cases 40-60 on servers where I had like 100+ when using router

my routers manufacturer speed is 100mbps, I conducted those tests on various parts of day & night, so that noone except for me was using the internet connection and / or wifi

also my pc is literally 100cm from router - so that they're connected physically with 100cm ethernet cable, so I guess that's not limiting factor

Comment: Check for a firmware update.  Also, check your rules and see if you've got unneeded firewall rules or filtering enabled.

Comment: Try power cycling the router. If that does not help, then do a firmware update, _even if it would be the same firmware. PS: Which version of that router? There are at least six...